# Don't show Data in DataGrid

Tags: c#, silverlight, silverlight-4.0, wcf-ria-services

in my app, I used WCF Services for load data from SQL DB then in Completed Event Handler of my ServiceClient write this code:

```
void svc_GetOrdersCompleted(object sender, GetOrdersCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Error == null)
    {
         dgOrders.ItemsSource = e.Result;
         txtStatus.Text = "";
    }
    else
         txtStatus.Text = "Error occured while loading orders from database";
}
```

dgOrders is my DataGrid and And AutoGenerateColumns set to True. 
in line 5: eResult have a number of Order objects but after this code DataGrid can't show data. Why?

this ia my xaml for dgOrders:

```
    <data:DataGrid x:Name="dgOrders"
                   Grid.Row="0"
                   Grid.Column="1"
                   AutoGenerateColumns="True"
                   SelectionChanged="dgOrders_SelectionChanged" Foreground="Green">
    </data:DataGrid>
```

this is [my Source code](http://rapidshare.com/files/391646199/DataApplication.zip.html)
please guide me.

Comment: Could you share your xaml for dgOrders?

Comment: I looked at your project. After removing all the controls from the app except the grid it worked fine, I also didn't use the sql data context. You should provide simplified version of your problem because no one won't waste time to get familiar with your projects specifics. My advice is when you post a sample code or project to create a separate project and including only related to the problem pieces. For example you should remove sql connection and return simple data.

Answer (score 0):

First - do e.Result contains any data ?
For more help you really need to share more info.

[here a sample project](http://www.filesavr.com/VIC0aNoJ) where that scenario works fine.